# Database.yml - setting up environment groups

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-4-2-1

Using ruby 2.5, rails 4.2.11,

I'm setting up a dev environment for a ruby project that used to just send straight to production.

HotWire contains application specific data while QualityDC contains much of the relational information shared by the other applications. How would I set it up so I can add a QualityDC_Dev instance to be used by the development.rb environment?

In the database.yml file (that references odbc.ini in my /etc folder, I have the following:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: HotWire_Dev
  username: webserver
  password: password
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

qualitydc:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: qualitydc
  username: webserver
  password: wordpass
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: HotWire
  username: webserver
  password: password
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

odbc.ini entries:

```
[BrazeWire]
Driver          = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
Server          = server.domain.com
Database        = HotWire
tds_version     = 8.0
Port            = 1433

[BrazeWire_Test]
Driver          = /usr/lib64/libtdsodbc.so.0
Server          = server.domain.com
Database        = HotWire_Dev
tds_version     = 8.0
Port            = 1433'

[QUALITYDC]
Driver      = FreeTDS
Server      = server.domain.com
Database    = QualityDC
tds_version     = 8.0
Port        = 1433
```

Comment: Are you really using Rails 2.4.11?

Comment: I work for a very big company that is super outdated...not my choice. But no it was a type, 4.2.11 - not much better

Answer (score 1):

Found another thread that referenced it, since 4.2 doesn't support grouping, had to make a janky workaround:

```
Using ruby 2.5, rails 4.2.11,

I'm setting up a dev environment for a ruby project that used to just send straight to production.

HotWire contains application specific data while QualityDC contains much of the relational information shared by the other applications. How would I set it up so I can add a QualityDC_Dev instance to be used by the development.rb environment?

In the database.yml file (that references odbc.ini in my /etc folder, I have the following:

development:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: HotWire_Dev
  username: webserver
  password: password
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

development_qualitydc:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: qualitydc_Dev
  username: webserver
  password: wordpass
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: HotWire
  username: webserver
  password: password
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production_qualitydc:
  adapter: sqlserver
  mode: odbc
  dsn: qualitydc
  username: webserver
  password: wordpass
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

And in the models:

```
class HotWire< ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "#{Rails.env}_qualitydc"
    self.table_name = 'QualityDC.dbmaster.HotWire'
  #set_primary_key :id_number
end
```